# simple currency converter using switch c++

Tags: c++, currency

Hello I need help with this simple calculator using switch
when I type in the currency I want to convert into and then the amount after that nothing happens
.Ive tried using if but i cant get it to work

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  char zlote;
  char E, D, F;
  char euro;
  char dolar;
  char funt;
  char currency;

  E=euro*0.25;
  D=dolar*0.19;
  F=funt*0.22;

  cout << "what currency do you want to convert into  ?" << endl;
  cin >> currency;

  cout<<"Type in the amount you wish to convert"<<endl;
  cin >>zlote;

  switch (zlote) {
    
     {case 1 :
       cout<<zlote<<" zlote is equal "<<E<<" Euro"<<endl;
       break;}

      {case 2 :
      cout<< zlote<<" zlote is equal "<<D<<" Dolarow"<<endl;
      break;}

      {case 3 :
      cout<< zlote<<" zlote is equal "<<F<<" Funtow"<<endl;
      break;}
  }
      return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: `{case 1 :` should be `{case '1' :` remember you are comparing characters. 1 is different from '1'

Comment: _`E=euro*0.25;`_ that's not going to work well ever.

Comment: FYI, you don't need braces surrounding cases.

Comment: Using a debugger is also good advice. It's very clear you did not step through the code line by line in a debugger looking at the variables and flow at each step. If you did so you would have spotted several of the problems very easily.

Answer (score 2):

> switch (zlote) {

should be switching on the currency choice, not the amount, right?  That's why nothing happens.

But you have other problems:  you seem to be computing stuff before you have the values input!

I would suggest following one important code-review issue in particular, to prevent that issue:  Don't declare your variables at the top in one clump; declare them when first used and ready to be given an initial value.

The types don't make any sense either.  Why are you multiplying characters by floating-point numbers?
**READ THE WARNINGS**; they actually are telling you things.

You switch won't work anyway, even if you used the right variable, because you read a `char` but you are switching on a numeric value, so that will be the character code:  `'1'` is not the same as `1` (it's actually 49 if memory serves).

Comment: Also never inputted `euro`, `dolar`, `funt` but used these to calculate `E`, `D` and `F` not  `zlote` which has the amount.

Comment: Yes, "seem to be computing stuff before you have the values input!"

Comment: I thought it was slightly different because the value of these were never input. If the formulas used `zlote` I would not have commented. Either way you got my +1 because it covers the problems.

Comment: Slightly... I made the comment before seeing that they were _never_ input; just that they had not been input up to that point.  "before" is the key thing to learn though; it's not wrong just because it's "never", in that adding it but later will not fix it.  Someone used to spreadsheets might not intuit the commands are issued in order, for example.  At least, I can only imagine why that happens to certain newcomers.

Answer (score 2):

Try
using case `E` instead of case `1`

using case `D` instead of case `2`

using case `F` instead of case `3`

Also when you take input from the user make sure You enter the letters in uppercase

Comment: Why is that the solution?

Comment: Because you are taking characters as Input and in the code above you are comparing character with numbers in Switch statement which does not work. Have a look on this link https://www.educative.io/edpresso/how-to-use-the-switch-statement-in-c

Comment: You could use `case '1':` but the program should indicate the valid choices.

Comment: That's only one of the many issues.

Answer (score -3):

In your code have diferents problems. I list the diferents problems and expose the diferents solutions:

**Problems**
1- You are declaring all the variable with type char. The type char only store one byte and you can not operate with decimals or integer numbers.

2 -You are using diferents variable to save the user input and calculate the conversion in the functions.

3- You have the functions that convert type of money before the user input. This is a problem because you can not calculate the conversion if you not have the quantity.

4 -The switch not have the correct variable to select the case.

**Solutions**

1 - I recommend you that search in the C++ documentation the diferents type of variables ans what is posible to store inside.
I use float type beacause is posible to operate wiht decimals numbers but you can use diferents types like double or long.

2 - If you request to user an input i recomend you to use the same variable to calculate the conversion but you can use an other and equals the both variables befor the conversion functions.

3 -The functions must be located after the request input or calculate the conversion inside every case in swtich.

4 - The siwtch need the variable of the same type that case identifyer.
If you put numbers ex. 1,2,3 you need to put an integer variable.

**Improvments**
You can improve your code checking the inputa data, because if user specify an option that not are defined in siwtch your code not print any think output.
You can add default case in siwtch. to this cases.

I attach the link to review the funcitonality of switch:

[https://www.w3schools.com/cpp/cpp_switch.asp](http://You%20can%20improve%20your%20code%20checking%20the%20inputa%20data,%20because%20if%20user%20specify%20an%20option%20that%20not%20are%20defined%20in%20siwtch%20your%20code%20not%20print%20any%20think%20output.%20%20You%20can%20add%20default%20case%20in%20siwtch.%20to%20this%20cases.%20%20I%20attach%20the%20link%20to%20review%20the%20funcitonality%20of%20switch%20https://www.w3schools.com/cpp/cpp_switch.asp)

```
float zlote;
float E, D, F;  
int currency;
cout << "what currency do you want to convert into  ?" << endl;
cin >> currency;

cout<<"Type in the amount you wish to convert"<<endl;
cin >>zlote;

   E=zlote*0.25;
   D=zlote*0.19;
   F=zlote*0.22;

   switch (currency)

   {

       {case 1 :
         cout<<zlote<<" zlote is equal "<<E<<" Euro"<<endl;
         break;}

        {case 2 :
        cout<< zlote<<" zlote is equal "<<D<<" Dolarow"<<endl;
        break;}

        {case 3 :
        cout<< zlote<<" zlote is equal "<<F<<" Funtow"<<endl;
        break;}


   }
```

Comment: You fixed a problem but there is more than 1 problem.

Comment: Yes, the type of variable are not correct.

Comment: You should also explain what change you made and why.

Comment: I am with @drescherjm, code only answers without any explanation are almost useless.

Comment: I'm OK with an answer that focusses on one-and-only one problem, but it needs to be well explained. Explain the problem and why it is a problem what problem. Explain the solution and why it works. If there are multiple viable solutions it can be worth explaining why one solution is preferable to others.